# Two Dropdown with some conditions

Tags: javascript

I have a situation here, I have Two drop-down selectors the options of the second selector is depends on the option of the first selector.
So, the second dropdown is last, so if someone select options from the second drop-down, it should redirect to a specific URL.

Sorting is working is there anybody to help in redirection, here is my code so far

**HTML**

```
<div class="category_div" id="category_div">Please Select Weeks:
    <select name="category" class="required-entry" id="category" onchange="javascript: firstdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
        <option value="">Select Weeks</option>
        <option value="Week 1">Week 1</option>
        <option value="Week 2">Week 2</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="sub_category_div" id="sub_category_div">Please Select Days:
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        document.write('<select name="subcategory" id="subcategory" ><option  value="">Select Days</option></select>');
    </script>
    <noscript>
        <select name="subcategory" id="subcategory"">
            <option value="">Select Days</option>
        </select>
    </noscript>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function firstdropdown(listindex)
{

    document.getElementById("subcategory").length = 0;
    switch (listindex)
    {
        case "Week 1" :
            document.getElementById("subcategory").options[0]=new Option("Please select days for week 1","");
            document.getElementById("subcategory").options[1]=new Option("Day 1","http://www.example.org");
            document.getElementById("subcategory").options[2]=new Option("Day 2","http://www.example.com");
            document.getElementById("subcategory").options[3]=new Option("Day 3","http://www.example.net");
            document.getElementById("subcategory").options[4]=new Option("Day 4","http://www.example.com");
            document.getElementById("subcategory").options[5]=new Option("Day 5","http://www.example.net");
            break;

        case "Week 2" :
            document.getElementById("subcategory").options[0]=new Option("Please select days for week 2","");
            document.getElementById("subcategory").options[1]=new Option("Day 1","http://www.example.org");
            document.getElementById("subcategory").options[2]=new Option("Day 2","http://www.example.com");
            document.getElementById("subcategory").options[3]=new Option("Day 3","http://www.example.net");
            document.getElementById("subcategory").options[4]=new Option("Day 4","http://www.example.com");
            document.getElementById("subcategory").options[5]=new Option("Day 5","http://www.example.net");
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: add an onchange to your second where you set the window.local to match the value if the selected index > 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added function redirect that contain event; then  get value of selected opt with event.target.value 
To redirect i used window.location.href
Try this example :
html:

```
<div class="category_div" id="category_div">Please Select Weeks:
    <select name="category" class="required-entry" id="category" onchange="javascript: firstdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
        <option value="">Select Weeks</option>
        <option value="Week 1">Week 1</option>
        <option value="Week 2">Week 2</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="sub_category_div" id="sub_category_div" onchange="redirect(event)">Please Select Days:
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        document.write('<select name="subcategory" id="subcategory" ><option  value="">Select Days</option></select>');
    </script>
    <noscript>
        <select name="subcategory" id="subcategory">
            <option value="">Select Days</option>
        </select>
    </noscript>
</div>
```

js :

```
function firstdropdown(listindex)
{

    document.getElementById("subcategory").length = 0;
    switch (listindex)
    {
        case "Week 1" :
            document.getElementById("subcategory").options[0]=new Option("Please select days for week 1","");
            document.getElementById("subcategory").options[1]=new Option("Day 1","http://www.example.org");
            document.getElementById("subcategory").options[2]=new Option("Day 2","http://www.example.com");
            document.getElementById("subcategory").options[3]=new Option("Day 3","http://www.example.net");
            document.getElementById("subcategory").options[4]=new Option("Day 4","http://www.example.com");
            document.getElementById("subcategory").options[5]=new Option("Day 5","http://www.example.net");
            break;

        case "Week 2" :
            document.getElementById("subcategory").options[0]=new Option("Please select days for week 2","");
            document.getElementById("subcategory").options[1]=new Option("Day 1","http://www.example.org");
            document.getElementById("subcategory").options[2]=new Option("Day 2","http://www.example.com");
            document.getElementById("subcategory").options[3]=new Option("Day 3","http://www.example.net");
            document.getElementById("subcategory").options[4]=new Option("Day 4","http://www.example.com");
            document.getElementById("subcategory").options[5]=new Option("Day 5","http://www.example.net");
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
function redirect(event){
window.location.href = event.target.value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! @mgasmi one more question is there any way to open that link in new tab?

Comment: @RoshanKumar yes change window.location.href = event.target.value; to 
window.open(event.target.value,'_blank');

Comment: One more help if you could help me out

I just want to print the current week and day in paragraph
If i would select week 2 and day 3 then it should insert in p tag like this

<p id="wk">Week 2</p>
<p id="dy">Day3</p>